# How did my Hosts file change?

Tags: administration, hosts

Let me start this by saying I do not or never have had Admin access to my Mac.

**Issue:** Recently when I tried to navigate to the URL dev.local.com which was mapped to a specific IP address in my Hosts file I was redirected to some weird generic search page. I had been using the URL for the last 4 months.

**Background:** The developer before me had the Hosts file updated with the specific IP's and their domains when they setup the local development environment. These updates were done by Tech Support who has admin access.

**Question:** If I do not have admin access how is it that the Hosts file is empty and shows "zero bytes"? Could I have accidentally deleted the contents? Could some sort of a virus do that to a Hosts file?

**Possible Cause:** A lot of this started happening after a third party tried setting up another Virtual Box on my machine to include some other "module" to our development environment. This was never completed correctly but I thought it was weird this all started around the same time. I do not believe they had the access to edit the Hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Mac's but installation of VitualBox and its components, even at the very basic level, will require some sort of administrative access to the machine. Without knowing what has been done and what access rights were given to your third party vendor for the installation of virtualbox, it is next to impossible to tell the root cause of your problems but it is quite plausible that, their actions might have caused the unintentional change in the hosts file.

Also, some sort of malware might made it into your system, during these installation attempts and might have caused some havoc.

It really is not possible to determine what happened unless an admin with more than basic skills puts his or her hands on the system and analyze logs and looks at all ins and outs. With the data you provided, it is not possible to tell the root cause.

Comment: Thank you @melBurslan  for the quick follow up. Would it be possible for me to review the dates a file has changed and what was changed? Similar to "Stat" but I was looking for as much detail to what has changed in a file and when

Comment: Again, not Familiar with MACs but, in order to see _"what changed in a file when"_ kind of information, requires some sort of auditing enabled. A quick google search brought this discussion up. I am not sure how much of this discussion contents apply to you but at least it is some place to start :https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/562291-how-to-audit-log-file-access-events-on-mac-os-x